# Trying to make an array of DirectX vertex with out knowing until run time what type they will be

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, memory, directx

Bit of background for those who don't know DirectX. A vertex is not just an XYZ position, it *can* have other data in it as well. DirectX uses a system known as Flexible Vertex Format, FVF, to let you define what format you want your vertexs to be in. You define these by passing a number to DirectX that use bitwise or to build it up, eg `(D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)`means you are going to start using (from when you tell DirectX) vertexs that have an XYZ (three floats) and a RGB components (DWORD / unsigned long).

In order to pass your vertexs to the graphics card, you basicaly lock the memory in the graphics card where your buffer is, and use memcpy to transfer your array over.

Your array is an array of a struct you deffine your self, so in this case you would have made a struct like...

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX {
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    DWORD COLOR;
};
```

You then make an array of type CUSTOMVERTEX and fill in the data fields.

I think my best appraoch is let my class build up an array of each component type, so an array of `struct pos{ flaot x,y,z;};` an array of `struct colour{ DWROD colour;};` etc.

But I will then need to merge these together so that I have an array structs like CUSTOMVERTEX.

Now, I think I have made a function that will merge to arrays together, but I am not sure if it is going to work as intended, here it is (currently missing the abilaty to actually return this 'interlaced' array)

```
void Utils::MergeArrays(char *ArrayA, char *ArrayB, int elementSizeA, int elementSizeB, int numElements)
{
    char *packedElements = (char*)malloc(numElements* (elementSizeA, elementSizeB));
    char *nextElement = packedElements;
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(nextElement, (void*)ArrayA[i], elementSizeA);
        nextElement += elementSizeA;
        memcpy(nextElement, (void*)ArrayB[i], elementSizeB);
        nextElement += elementSizeB;
    }
}
```

when calling this function, you will pass in the two arrays you want merged, and size of the elements in each array and the number of elements in your array.

I was asking about this in chat for a while whilst SO was down. A few things to say.

I am dealing with fairly small data sets, like 100 tops, and this (in theory) is more of an initialisation task, so should only get done once, so a bit of time is ok by me.

My final array that I want to be able to use memcpy on to transfer into the graphics card needs to have no padding, it has to be contiguous data.

**EDIT** The combined array of vertex data will be transfered to the GPU, this is first done by requesting the GPU to set a void* to the start of the memory I have access to and requesting space the size of my  customVertex * NumOfVertex. So if my mergeArray function does loose what the types are within it, that is ok, just a long as I get my single combined array to transfer in one block **/EDIT**

Finally, their is a dam good chance I am barking up the wrong tree with this, so their may well be a much simpler way to just not have this problem in the first place, but part of me has dug my heals in and wants to get this system working, so I would appreciate knowing how to get such a system to work (the interlacing arrays thing)

Thank you so much... I need to sooth my head now, so I look forward to hearing any ideas on the problem.

Comment: what probelm are you facing with array of CUSTOMERVERTEX? Why are you thinking of separating our VERTEX and COLOR?

Comment: I am not trying to separate them out, I want to take the arrays of components and merge them together so that I have the one array of type customvertex, except, I don't know WHAT exactly until run time my FVF (thus what data is in my custom vertex)  will be.

Comment: You know the FVF format hasn't been necessary since DX8, right?

Comment: @jalf wait what? I know I could just load .x files

Comment: Check the D3D docs on vertex buffers. Assuming you're not looking at the DX8 version, they mention that you *can* create a FVF buffer, but also describe how you can use vertex declarations to achieve much the same thing, but with more flexibility. The only case where FVF is *necessary* is if you want to write into a vertex buffer with `ProcessVertices`. Read up at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206332%28VS.85%29.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204869%28VS.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173428%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering your code, this should do it:

```
void* Utils::MergeArrays(char *ArrayA, char *ArrayB, int elementSizeA, int elementSizeB, int numElements)
{
    char *packedElements = (char*)malloc(numElements* (elementSizeA + elementSizeB));
    char *nextElement = packedElements;
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(nextElement, ArrayA + i*elementSizeA, elementSizeA);
        nextElement += elementSizeA;
        memcpy(nextElement, ArrayB + i*elementSizeB, elementSizeB);
        nextElement += elementSizeB;
    }
    return packedElements;
}
```

Note that you probably want some code that merges all the attributes at once, rather than 2 at a time (think position+normal+texture coordinate+color+...). Also note that you can do that merging at the time you fill out your vertex buffer, so that you don't ever need to allocate `packedElements`.

Something like:

```
//pass the Locked buffer in as destArray
void Utils::MergeArrays(char* destArray, char **Arrays, int* elementSizes, int numArrays, int numElements)
{
    char* nextElement = destArray;
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        for (int array=0; array<numArrays; ++array)
        {
            int elementSize = elementSizes[array];
            memcpy(nextElement, Arrays[array] + i*elementSize, elementSize);
            nextElement += elementSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so rather then merging the arrays two at a time, I pass the function the space in memory I want it to merge the arrays to and array of arrays, the number of arrays and the size of the arrays. But how do I let this function know what the size of the elements are in each array?

Comment: @thecoshman: elementSizes stores the size of the element in each array. the "size of the arrays" is inferred from elementSizes and numElements.

Comment: I am accepting this answer a far bit after actually moving on from the problem. From what I can remember, this would have solved my problem. Though it might have needed some modification, either to this function, or to my surrounding code.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine.  But if you want something a bit more C++ish, you could try something like this:

**Edit** My previous solution basically recreated something that already existed, std::pair.  I don't know what I was thinking, here's the even more C++ish solution:

```
template<typename InIt_A, typename InIt_B, typename OutIt>
void MergeArrays(InIt_A ia, InIt_B ib, OutIt out, std::size_t size)
{
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        *out = make_pair(*ia,*ib);
        ++out;
        ++ia;
        ++ib;
    }
}

int main()
{
    pos p[100];
    color c[100];
    typedef pair<pos,color> CustomVertex;
    CustomVertex cv[100];

    MergeArrays(p,c,cv,100);
}
```

You shouldn't have to worry about padding, because all elements in a D3D vertex are either 32 bit floats, or 32 bit integers.

**Edit**

Here's a solution that might work.  It will do all your mergings at once, and you don't need to worry about passing around the size:

```
// declare a different struct for each possible vertex element
struct Position { FLOAT x,y,z; };
struct Normal { FLOAT x,y,z; };
struct Diffuse { BYTE a,r,g,b; };
struct TextureCoordinates { FLOAT u,v; };
// etc...

// I'm not all too sure about all the different elements you can have in a vertex
// But you would want a parameter for each one in this function.  Any element that
// you didn't use, you would just pass in a null pointer.  Since it's properly
// typed, you won't be able to pass in an array of the wrong type without casting.
std::vector<char> MergeArrays(Position * ppos, Normal * pnorm, Diffuse * pdif, TextureCoordinates * ptex, int size)
{
    int element_size = 0;
    if(ppos) element_size += sizeof(Position);
    if(pnorm) element_size += sizeof(Normal);
    if(pdif) element_size += sizeof(Diffuse);
    if(ptex) element_size += sizeof(TextureCoordinates);

    vector<char> packed(element_size * size);

    vector<char>::iterator it = packed.begin();
    while(it != packed.end())
    {
        if(ppos)
        {
            it = std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ppos), sizeof(Position), it);
            ppos++;
        }

        if(pnorm)
        {
            it = std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pnorm), sizeof(Normal), it);
            pnorm++;
        }

        if(pdif)
        {
            it = std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pdif), sizeof(Diffuse), it);
            pdif++;
        }

        if(ptex)
        {
            it = std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptex), sizeof(TextureCoordinates), it);
            ptex++;
        }

    }

    return packed;
}

// Testing it out.  We'll create an array of 10 each of some of the elements.
// We'll use Position, Normal, and Texture Coordinates.  We'll pass in a NULL
// for Diffuse.
int main() 
{
    Position p[10];
    Normal n[10];
    TextureCoordinates tc[10];

    // Fill in the arrays with dummy data that we can easily read.  In this
    // case, what we'll do is cast each array to a char*, and fill in each
    // successive element with an incrementing value.
    for(int i=0; i<10*sizeof(Position); i++)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<char*>(p)[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10*sizeof(Normal); i++)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<char*>(n)[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10*sizeof(TextureCoordinates); i++)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<char*>(tc)[i] = i;
    }

    vector<char> v = MergeArrays(p,n,NULL,tc,10);

    // Output the vector.  It should be interlaced:
    // Position-Normal-TexCoordinates-Position-Normal-TexCoordinates-etc...
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [](const char & c) { cout << (int)c << endl; });
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that at compile time I would need to know that I want to merge position and colour, but I simple don't. It is not until run time that I know what elements I am merging. As such, I need the merge array function to work so that it will not care what size the individual elements are. It dose not matter if my 'out array' loose what type the data is, as long as it is packed correctly, becuase when I transfer it to the GPU, it is done so into a void* or size custom vertex * number of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no. The FVF system has been deprecated for years and isn't even available in D3D10 or later. D3D9 uses the VertexElement system. Sample code:

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 VertexColElements[] =
{
    {0, 0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0},
    {0, 12, D3DDECLTYPE_D3DCOLOR, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_COLOR, 0},
    D3DDECL_END(),
};
```

The FVF system has a number of fundamental flaws - for example, which order the bytes go in.

On top of that, if you want to make a runtime-variant vertex data format, then you will need to write a shader for every possible variant that you may want to have, and compile them all, and spend your life swapping them around. And, the effects on the final product would be insane - for example, how could you possibly write a competitive rendering engine if you decide to take out the lighting data you need to Phong shade?

The reality is that a runtime-variant vertex format is more than a tad insane.

However, I guess I'd better lend a hand. What you really need is a polymorphic function object and some plain memory- D3D takes void*s or somesuch so that's not a big deal. When you call the function object, it adds to the FVF declaration and copies data into the memory.

```
class FunctionBase {
public:
    virtual ~FunctionBase() {}
    virtual void Call(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& vertices, std::vector<D3DVERTEXELEMENT9>& vertexdecl, int& offset) = 0;
};
// Example implementation
class Position : public FunctionBase {
    virtual void Call(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& vertices, std::vector<D3DVERTEXELEMENT9>& vertexdecl, int& offset) {
        std::for_each(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), [&](std::vector<char>& data) {
            float x[3] = {0};
            char* ptr = (char*)x;
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++) {
                data.push_back(ptr[i]);
            }
        }
        vertexdecl.push_back({0, offset, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0});
        offset += sizeof(x);
    }
};

std::vector<std::vector<char>> vertices;
std::vector<D3DVERTEXELEMENT9> vertexdecl;
vertices.resize(vertex_count);
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FunctionBase>> functions;
// add to functions here
int offset = 0;
std::for_each(functions.begin(), functions.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<FunctionBase>& ref) {
    ref->Call(vertices, vertexdecl, offset);
});
vertexdecl.push_back(D3DDECL_END());
```

Excuse my use of lambdas, I use a C++0x compiler.

Comment: Ok I probably should have said, I am stuck with DirectX9, and I am not bothering with shaders for this course work. I don't see though how tour code will let me make an array of vertexs, where I don't knwo what they look like untill runtime, to copy over to the GPU

Comment: @thecoshman: Because the vertices and the vertex format are built dynamically? All you have to do is fill the functionbase vector with objects and it builds itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know DirectX, but the exact same sort of concept exists in OpenGL, and in OpenGL you can specify the location and stride of each vertex attribute.  You can have alternating attributes (like your first struct) or you scan store them in different blocks.  In OpenGL you use glVertexPointer to set these things up.  Considering that DirectX is ultimately running on the same hardware underneath, I suspect there's some way to do the same thing in DirectX, but I don't know what it is.

Some Googling with DirectX and glVertexPointer as keywords turns up SetFVF and SetVertexDeclaration

[MSDN on SetFVF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174464%28VS.85%29.aspx), [gamedev discussion comparing them](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=314480)

Comment: You are right in what you are saying, but when you set your FVF you are saying that you are going to pass in a vertex made of these components. The array of vertices you pass in will need to be of type struct A, the fields with in struct A are determined by what FVF you are wanting to use, so if you  tried to transfer an array of vertex data that had an extra component in, you will just horribly mess up your program, as the last few fields of the first vertex would become the first of the second and so on.

Comment: I think this describes the DX way to do what I was trying to describe in GL:  http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=431127